# Get data from XML sites

Tags: php, xml

I want to get some data from a site based on xml's.
The problem is I need to be logged to it as a PublicUser without password.

I have tryed:

```
$url = 'http://IP/wcd/system_counter.xml';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
echo $content
```

But i only get this:

```
err En ReloginAttempt /wcd/index.html false
```

This is the xml code used for loggin:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="top.xsl" type="text/xsl"?>
<MFP>
<SelNo>Auto</SelNo>
<LangNo>En</LangNo>
<Service><Setting><AuthSetting><AuthMode><AuthType>None</AuthType>
<ListOn>false</ListOn>
<PublicUser>true</PublicUser>
<BoxAdmin>false</BoxAdmin>
</AuthMode><TrackMode><TrackType>None</TrackType></TrackMode></AuthSetting>
<MiddleServerSetting><ControlList><ArraySize>0</ArraySize></ControlList><Screen>
<Id>0</Id></Screen></MiddleServerSetting>
</Setting></Service><LangDummy>false</LangDummy></MFP>
```

Is there a way to send the user as well when i want to get the XML info ?

Comment: So you POST(?) that XML in your request body to their site and receive a token to put in header for further requests?

Comment: Yes, after I'm logged this is the start of the XML:
 <LoginMode>PublicUser</LoginMode>
I didnt find how to send the <LoginMode>PublicUser</LoginMode> when i request the page ( $url = 'http://IP/wcd/system_counter.xml'; )

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access pages requiring posted login information using file_get_contents. Instead you need to use curl. Something along these lines:

```
$ch = curl_init($url); // The url you want to call

curl_setopt_array(
    $ch, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_POST           => 1,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $login_xml, // The xml login in string form
    )
);

//getting response from server
$response = curl_exec($ch);

echo curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: the expected content-type for the request body might vary from the one your example would create. also it's possible to to post a request body with `file_get_contents` as well.